# Push on to array until some value

Tags: arrays, perl

Say I'm looping through some data file that contains header lines. For example,

```
>Header 1
data1
data2
data3
>Header 2
data4
data5
data6
>Header 3
```

I want to push all of the header lines into a `@headers` array, and then all of the data in a `@data` array. The relationship should be 1:1, i.e. so that the first element of `@headers` is ">Header 1" and the first element of `@data` is "data1data2data3". How can I accomplish this?  So far, I have

```
my @data;
my @headers;
while(<$fh>){
  chomp($_);

  if($_ =~ /(>)/){
      push @headers, $_;
  }
  else{ 
     push @data, $_;    

  }
}
```

Which puts each line of data into its own index in `@data`. Basically if the line begins with a ">" push it to the `@headers` array, else push it to the `@data` array as long as the next line doesn't start with ">". Not quite sure how to code that last part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `push` to `@data` when there is no header. That would add a new element. What you want to do is *append* to the last element. Perl allows you to use the index `[-1]` to get the last element of an array. So you can easily add a new element to `@data` at the same time you add one to `@headers`, because they correspond.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my (@headers, @data);

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp; # no need for $_ here

    if ( m/^>/ ) { # no need for $_ here either
        push @headers, $_;
        push @data, q{}; # the empty string
    } else {
        $data[-1] .= $_;
    }
}

__DATA__
>Header 1
data1
data2
data3
>Header 2
data4
data5
data6
>Header 3
```

This will produce these to data structures (output with [Data::Printer](https://p3rl.org/Data::Printer)).

```
[
    [0] ">Header 1",
    [1] ">Header 2",
    [2] ">Header 3"
]
[
    [0] "data1data2data3",
    [1] "data4data5data6",
    [2] ""
]
```

Note that in most cases, you don't need to use `$_` explicitly because many operators use them by default if nothing else is given. You also do not need a capture group `()` in your pattern around the bracket. You're not using `$1`, so that's a waste of resources.

Comment: Thanks @simbabque. This helps my understanding a lot

Comment: Hey @simbabque, just a follow up question. Why does the empty string need to be added? Won't that cause a mismatch in indicies of the two arrays? Or does the appending replace the empty string?

Comment: @KyleWeise you need to add something so the last index goes one up. If you add the undefined value and then append you will get a warning about using an undefined value in a concatenation. If you use the empty string, you will not. Appending text to an empty string will give you essentially the text. It will not be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Following your coding, we could have:

```
my (@data, @headers, @sequences);

while( <$fh> ) {
  chomp($_);

  if( $_ =~ /(>)/ ) {
    push @headers, $_;
    push @data, join @sequences;
    @sequences = ();
  }
  else { 
    push @sequences, $_;   
  }
}
push @data, join @sequences;
```

Every time a new header is found, the data is accummulated and the sequence starts anew. At the end of the loop you need to do the *final* accummulation.

Also note @simbabque comments about not needing to use `$_` with most built ins. I have not changed the code to avoid confussion.

Comment: unfortunately, both solutions do need to do 'something' with `@data` when we're inside the `head` conditional-branch. But the nice thing with the `@sequences` is that we can do a `push @data, join ', ', @sequences` which makes that string a bit more readable

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys, `@sequences` and `@data`are actually the same array. In my actual code I have it as `@sequences` and thought `@data` would be more explicit in the context of my question. I edited this in my original question. Regardless, this is interesting solution nonetheless!

Comment: When I saw the question there was no `@sequences` at all.